# How to speed up number === in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have some performance problems in JS code. I have the function in JS:

```
function() {
    var up = this.parentCtx === null ? "" : this.parentCtx.toString();
    if (up.length === 0) {
        if (this.returnState === this.EMPTY_RETURN_STATE) {
            return "$";
        } else {
            return "" + this.returnState;
        }
    } else {
        return "" + this.returnState + " " + up;
    }
};
```

When I profile code in Google Chrome, I saw that
`this.returnState === this.EMPTY_RETURN_STATE` takes more CPU time. Has been any ways to speed up it?

Comment: if you're worried about the time a simple strict equality test takes, then you're probably micro-optimizing. there's nothing you can to do speed up an equality test, other than not doing it.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with numbers taking a long time - you are still selecting the properties, e.g., `this.x` which will trigger a potentially full property chain traversal. Depending on how deep that chain runs, that might be what's eating the time, not the `===` operator.

Comment: "I saw that this.returnState === this.EMPTY_RETURN_STATE" --- how did you "saw" that? Any profiling results?

Comment: Some "profiling" results is here - http://joxi.ru/12MZonocbjpMAJ

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing the value and the value type. Though this should not make much time difference. If the types can be compared directly (same type), then use the ==.

Comment: `==` doesn't compare the values _directly_. In fact, if it did, we wouldn't need the strict equals. The loose equals will (potentially) _convert_ the values if they are not of the same type. So `1 == "1"` will be `true` and it would involve change a value. In fact, `1 == "    1      "`  would also return `true`. As would `1 == "01"`. I am not familiar with JS implementation internals but I sincerely doubt that `===` would be significantly slower than having to do the conversion as part of the check.

Comment: I meant they have to be of the same type by saying 'directly'

Comment: "then use the ==." --- what this advice is based on? Any chance you have checked the specification before giving your answer?